# Windows onbeforeunload event

Tags: javascript, events

onbeforeunload does not fire on any browser (Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Safari) on my laptop.
The following example is from MDN web docs published in 2019.
For god sake why browsers behave sooooo stupid and do not fire the event.
I have lost hours of my life time watching the screen and wondering why this supposedly simple code does not work on any browser.
Am I really doing something wrong here or do I have an issue with my windows 10 on my laptop or the browser developers make the life hell for us?
The onbeforeunload event is very well documented by the browsers to be workable just as written bellow.
So why it does not work?

Used example from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

```
<html
<head>
<script language='javascript'  type='text/javascript'>
//This example is from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload
//I added the line alert('unloading')
//The alert is not shown so the onbeforeunload is not fired. Why?
alert('2')
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    alert('unloading')
  // Cancel the event
  e.preventDefault();
  // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
  e.returnValue = '';
}

);

</script>

</head>

<body>
    Tesing onbeforunload.
</body>

</html>
```

onbeforeunload must execute lines of code

Comment: "In some browsers, calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() may be ignored during this event. See the HTML specification for more details."

Comment: At the time of running the page, I saw an error in Chrome, "blocked alert during beforeunload". It seems like most browsers have removed onbeforeunload. Have a look here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/dialogs-policy

Comment: You shouldn't try to alert in this event handler. If it returns a string, the browser will display its own confirmation dialog that asks if the user really wants to leave the page.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Bottom line is that I

Comment: what is the alternative to the onbeforeunload which seems to be vanished suddenly?

Comment: I found a page at ```https://rawgit.com/jonnymoo/b960c889a6152ffd4a1ff32437991442/raw/leave.html``` which simply executes the onbeforeunload and it works on my laptop when I try the live page. But when I copy the source code of the page and try it on my laptop the onbeforeunload does not execute. Has anybody any idea why the same code does not fire the onbeforeunload on my laptop?

Comment: Hi @Dave ! where You able to find a solution to this ? Seems like i have exactly the same problem. Firefox does run my 'onbeforeunload' event, but chrome does not. This `https://rawgit.com/jonnymoo/b960c889a6152ffd4a1ff32437991442/raw/leave.html` link You provided does work on my chrome.